# Replacing a delimiter

Tags: unix, awk, sed, grep

I have a file with `^A` as a delimiter:

```
8bf9f1897035297fb7b0767e4e5e191b2c93ceb^AAustralia^A2016-01-13 05:19:06^A
8bf9f1897035297fb7b0767e4e5e191b2c93ceb^AAustralia^A2016-01-13 05:19:06^A
8bf9f1897035297fb7b0767e4e5e191b2c93ceb^AAustralia^A2016-01-13 05:19:06^A
```

How can I replace the delimiters with `|` using awk or sed?

Desired output:

```
8bf9f1897035297fb7b0767e4e5e191b2c93ceb|Australia|2016-01-13 05:19:06|
8bf9f1897035297fb7b0767e4e5e191b2c93ceb|Australia|2016-01-13 05:19:06|
8bf9f1897035297fb7b0767e4e5e191b2c93ceb|Australia|2016-01-13 05:19:06|
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If you are referring to the control-A character:

   - The following will work with both GNU and non-GNU sed: `sed 's/\x01/|/g'`
   - Possibly faster would be `tr '\001' '|'`
2. If you are referring to the two-character sequence `^A`:

   - `sed 's/\^A/|/g'`
   - in awk you could use `gsub( /\^A/,"|" )`

Answer (score 1):

If your version of `sed` is GNU sed, you can use [GNU Extensions for Escapes in Regular Expressions](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Escapes.html#Escapes), in particular:

> ```
> `\cX'
>      Produces or matches `CONTROL-X', where X is any character.  The
>      precise effect of `\cX' is as follows: if X is a lower case
>      letter, it is converted to upper case.  Then bit 6 of the
>      character (hex 40) is inverted.  Thus `\cz' becomes hex 1A, but
>      `\c{' becomes hex 3B, while `\c;' becomes hex 7B.
> ```

So that would be:

```
sed -e "s/\ca/|/" < input.txt
```